# Selenium test can be started via maven only. Fails with NullPointer when starting using TestNG xml file (because system variable is 'null')

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception, system-properties, maven-failsafe-plugin

The issue is the following - if I launch my autotests via maven(from command prompt OR eclipse), then they run without issues. If I try to launch via testng.xml(from eclipse), then my tests fail with NullPointerException. Basically here is my pom.xml with system variable called "**browser**"

```
<properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <!-- Dependency versions -->
      <selenium.version>LATEST</selenium.version>
      <!-- Configurable variables -->
      <threads>3</threads>
      <browser>chrome</browser>
      <overwrite.binaries>false</overwrite.binaries>
   </properties>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <parallel>methods</parallel>
               <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
               <systemPropertyVariables>
               <browser>${browser}</browser>
                  <!--Set properties passed in by the driverbinary downloader-->
                  <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                  <webdriver.ie.driver>${webdriver.ie.driver}</webdriver.ie.driver>
                  <webdriver.opera.driver>${webdriver.opera.driver}</webdriver.opera.driver>
               </systemPropertyVariables>
```

and here is the code I use to retrieve "**browser**" variable:

```
private final String browser=System.getProperty("browser").toUpperCase();
```

So, test always stops execution with the NullPointerException at the line above. The error is:

```
FAILED: secondTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DriverPackage.WebDriverThread.<init>(WebDriverThread.java:17)
```

BTW if I assign **browser** value in the following way (just like a text value):

```
private final String browser=("firefox").toUpperCase();
```

then test runs via Testng.xml too.

================

My thinking is that this is not about my code, but rather about approach. Maybe there are some things I'm not aware about which concern accessing system variables with the help of TestNG? What I'd like additionally mention is that I'm using maven-failsafe-plugin plugin (you may see it in pom.xml). Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can solve this.

1. Run using run confingurations.  Set the properties that you are setting in the pom in the vm arguments and specify your suite file.
2. In your xml, define parameters, which you can read using listeners and set static variables that can be referred in code.
3. Define a properties file, if system.getProperty(browser) is null then read the properties file and take the data from there.